Was Satan joking with God in Job 1: 6-7?
We read in Job 1:6-7 :

One  day the angels  came to present themselves before the LORD, and Satan also came with them.
The LORD said to Satan, "Where have you come from?" Satan answered the LORD, "From roaming through the earth and going back and forth in it."

Granted that the said conversation took place verbatim . Granted also that Satan was an uninvited guest in the meeting of God and His Angels. Isn't there something peculiar in Satan's verbose answer to God's simple query, especially in the phrase 'going back and forth in it ' ? Was he telling God that he was roaming the earth in the lookout for souls ? ( Connect that with Jesus' narrative of the expelled evil spirit roaming about on dry land - Mtt 12:43-45).Or, was he simply using a joke to state that he had no place on earth to stay ?  What is the take of Bible scholars  on the conversation ?

Granted also that Satan was an uninvited guest in the meeting of God and His Angels - what is this premise based on? The Hebrew in Job identifies the character as Ha-Satan, or the accuser. Jewish belief is that this episode occurred on Rosh Hashanah and the satan was performing its role as divine prosecutor, therefore was specifically an invited member of the divine council and one of the sons of G-d

This answer to "what is the take of Biblical scholars" begins with the Hebrew word "sut' (Str 7751).  It is in the phrase in v. 2.2, “from ‘going back & forth’ (sut) on the earth” . The Dictionary of Biblical Languages with Semantic Domains: Hebrew (Old Testament) notes that ‘sut’ designates "a more or less random linear motion through a geographical area, often to accomplish a particular purpose."  It compares the use of the word in Job 2:2 to Numbers 11:8 (where the Israelites went out looking for mana in the desert) & 2Sa 24:2, 8. (where David tells Joab to go & number Israel.)
This is not a new association.  Rashi (renowned medieval Jewish Rabbi) had noted the association of the term to Numbers 11:8, stating the term implies an effortless roaming around (or as stated by another answer on this page, "freely roamed.")  Contemporary Rabbi Moshe Eisemann writes in a commentary on Iyob (Job), Artscroll Tanach Series "but the context here seems to imply a more purposeful peregrination (i.e. journey)  Ramban (renowned medieval Jewish Rabbi) associates this term with searching out while Radak (renowned medieval Jewish Rabbi) reads a connotation of spying."
For Christians who recognize that [hasatan] is [the devil] that Jesus Christ speaks of as "ruler of this world" (John 12:31; 14:30; 16:11) it comes as no surprise that [hasatan] had been purposefully & effortlessly roaming around the world to search out & spy on man for [his] own evil & nefarious purpose to prove what man was, i.e. corrupt & abominable.
Getting back to the title question, 'was satan joking,' the answer may be best expressed by a paraphrasing & restating the event, focusing on & encompassing both Job 1:7-11 & 2:2-5.  (Of course this paraphrase/restating raises a number of questions so references will be made afterwards to substantiate/prove/defend this paraphrasing/restating.)
The ruler of the world, [hasatan], came before the LORD Who asked [him], "have [you] set [your] heart against My servant Job who is blameless & upright, fearing God & avoiding evil?"  [hasatan] responded, "You are wrong about Job. I have been all over the world, back & forth, up & down so I know man, all men. Job is no better than any & all men who are corrupt & abominable.  Put forth Your hand & touch all that he has & he will do what any man would do, what all men would do, he will curse You to Your face!"
Doesn't sound like a joke to me!
Nor does it sound like a heavenly prosecutor just doing his job. [hasatan] has real intense malice toward man. See also the beginning of Zechariah Chapter 3. According to [him] man is corrupt & abominable.  Man is a worm & a maggot.  When the LORD gave [hasatan] the freedom to test Job, [hasatan] murdered all of Job's children & many of his servants and stole Job's wealth & health.  We can safely assume from [hasatan's] response before the LORD the 2nd time that [he] would have murdered Job had not the LORD forbidden [him] to do so.  Job had stated (v 24:14) "the murderer rises at the light that [he] may kill the poor & the needy; & in the night [he] is as a thief."  Jesus had said "the devil was a murderer from the beginning.."
Compare this to the Saint Raphael in the Book of Tobit whom the LORD sent to test Tobit.  He caused Tobit to go blind & took his wealth but afterwards restored both & bound the demon "asmodeus" to free Tobit's relative Sarah from his malicious murders.  There was no malice in Saint Raphael only service, unlike [hasatan].
Justifications:
•   'ruler of the world' - See my Answers to the Questions "Is satan one of the sons of God?"; "Who is King over the Sons of Pride?" & John 12:31, 14:30, 16:11; & Revelation 12:9, 20:2
•   'Have [you] set [your] heart against' - See my Question "Had satan set his heart against Job?"
•   Man is corrupt & abominable - See my Answer to the Questions - "What is Eliphaz explaining in Job 4:12-21?" & "Why is Satan not mentioned again after Job  2:7?"
•   [hasatan] contradicts the LORD concerning Job (& man) because [he] knows all men - See my Answer to the Question - "What did Satan mean, when he replied to God, "Skin for Skin"?"
•   Of course for a more comprehensive justification see my videos on YouTube on The Book of Job & keyofcreation.  Or download the abridged & unabridged full analysis at keyofcreation.com.

There is no joke involved in Satan's statement - quite the opposite.
Satan is saying that he freely roams the earth - a Hebrew idea suggesting that he is ruler and master of all!  Gill reaches the same conclusion when he writes:

"then Satan answered the Lord and said, from going to and fro in the
earth, and from walking up and down in it"; thus he said as
swaggering and boasting, as if he was indeed the God of the whole
world, the Prince and King of it, and had and exercised a sovereign
dominion over it, and as such had been making a tour through it, and
taking a survey of it, see Matthew 4:8, and as if he was at full
liberty to go where he pleased, and was under no control [from God]

It is precisely as a counter to Satan's boastful attitude that God suggests Satan consider the Godly man, Job:

Job 1:8 - Then the LORD said to Satan, “Have you considered My servant
Job? For there is no one on earth like him, a man who is blameless and
upright, who fears God and shuns evil.”

That is, God is saying that whatever Satan is master of, he is NOT master of Job and his family!  This is what makes God's comment so stinging to Satan and why he complains because Satan has so access to job because of the "hedge around him" (V10).
From this, flows the rest of plot of the book.

I don't see anything in the text that indicates that Satan was joking.
For reference here is a larger portion of the passage for context.
Job 1

6 One day the angels came to present themselves before the Lord, and Satan also came with them. 7 The Lord said to Satan, “Where have you come from?”
Satan answered the Lord, “From roaming throughout the earth, going back and forth on it.”
8 Then the Lord said to Satan, “Have you considered my servant Job? There is no one on earth like him; he is blameless and upright, a man who fears God and shuns evil.”

God's response does not indicate that Satan was joking.
Possibly, since Satan has been roaming the earth he would be familiar with Job and Job's relationship with God. This understanding would better follow the flow of the story.
Based on the content of the book of Job the story is not intended to tell us

what Satan does as he roams
that Satan has nowhere on earth to stay

This is a story about the person and character of God and the faithfulness of Job.
